# How to find the Closing balance and open balance using laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

i have three tables `Stock table` with field `'inv_no', 'pid','qty','descp'` , `Loading table` with field `'sid','pid','qty','order_no'` and `products table` with `'name', 'Sprice','Bprice'`

my Logic: I want to find the Closing balance and open balance, formula of closing balance is 
***Closing_balance=Open_balance+today_Inward-today_OutWard***

*today_Inward* you can select `qty`from `stock` table and *today_OutWard*  from `loading` table

**Example:** suppose Item1 has the following details, open_balance= 0 today_Inward_qty= 100, today_OutWard_qty=60

So according to formula above closed_balance = 40

**MY CASE::** I want when i wake up tomorrow this closed_balance 40 qty is to be *open_balance* 40 qty, no matter if tomorrow i will not perform the outward_qty so this will remain as open_balance in the stock summary. if i perform entered new stock the open balance will effect as well.

How can archive this case?, someone can help me on this

this is Display of what i need to have final [image: Display of what i need to have final]

My controller of stock

```
 request()->validate([
        'descp' => 'required',
        'qty' => 'required',

         ]);

        $data=$request->all();
        // $lastid=Supplier::create($data)->id;
        if(count($request->pid) > 0)
        {
            foreach($request->pid as $key=>$v){
                $data2=([
                    'inv_no'=>$fk,
                    'pid'=>$request->pid [$key],
                    'qty'=>$request->qty [$key],
                    'descp'=>$request->descp,
                    // 'amount'=>$request->amount [$key],
                ]);

                Stock::create($data2);
                 }
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Successfully Stored');

        }
```

my controller of loading

```
     request()->validate([
        'sid' => 'required',
        'qty' => 'required',

         ]);

        $data=$request->all();
        if(count($request->pid) > 0)
        {
            foreach($request->pid as $key=>$v){
                $data2=([
                    'order_no'=>$fk,
                    'pid'=>$request->pid [$key],
                    'sid'=>$request->sid,
                    'qty'=>$request->qty [$key],
                ]);
                Loading::create($data2);
                 }
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Successfully Stored');

        }
```

my function of view stock summary(as you can seen on screenshot above)

```
      public function stockSummary(){

     $stockSummary=DB::table('products')
          ->select(['products.id','products.name'])
        ->addSelect([
        'total_stockIn' => DB::table('stocks')
          ->selectRaw('sum(ifnull(`stocks`.`qty`,0))')
          ->whereColumn('stocks.pid', '=', 'products.id')
          ->whereDate('stocks.created_at', '=', Carbon::today()),

    'total_loadings' => DB::table('loadings')
          ->selectRaw('sum(ifnull(`loadings`.`qty`,0))')
          ->whereColumn('loadings.pid', '=', 'products.id')
          ->whereDate('loadings.created_at', '=', Carbon::today()),

     'total_stock_jana' => DB::table('stocks')
         -> selectRaw('sum(ifnull(`stocks`.`qty`,0))')
          ->whereColumn('stocks.pid', '=', 'products.id')
          ->whereDate('stocks.created_at', '=', Carbon::yesterday()),

      'total_loadings_jana' => DB::table('loadings')
          ->selectRaw('sum(ifnull(`loadings`.`qty`,0))')
          ->whereColumn('loadings.pid', '=', 'products.id')
          ->whereDate('loadings.created_at', '=', Carbon::yesterday())
         ])->get()
       ->map(function ($item) {
                        $item->total_stockIn = $item->total_stockIn ?? 0;
           $item->total_stock_jana = $item->total_stock_jana  ?? 0;
                 $item->total_loading_jana = $item->total_loading_jana;
                     $item->total_loadings = $item->total_loadings ?? 0;

        $item->OB = $item->total_stock_jana -$item>total_loading_jana;
              $item->Totalstock = $item->OB + $item->total_stockIn;
                   $item->CB = $item->Totalstock - $item->total_loadings;
                        return $item;
                    });

       return view('stock.summary',compact('stockSummary'));

      }
```

Someone can help me to modify and get me the clear idea in laravel.

Comment: This question is unclear as-is -- please add the creation statements for the three input tables, and insert statements for example values

Comment: the code is updated now

Comment: Ok I would suggest MySQL DDL and insert statements -- easier to write SQL answers if that is what you're looking for

Comment: Ok advice, sql statement